# unable to call getter method

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++-cli, c++builder

I am trying to get the value of x and y after the user input,
placed the values in a consturctor,
and using `getX()` and `getY()` method in `Point.cpp` to do some calculations but the thing is, it always returns `X:0 Y:0` and I have no idea why. My code is below

Point.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;

     Point::Point(int x,int y)  {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
     } 

     int Point::getX() {
       return x;
     }

     int Point::getY() {
       return y;
     }

     void Point::setX(int x) {
       this->x = x;
     }

     void Point::setY(int y) {
      this->y = y;
    } 

    void Point::someMethods() {
       x = getX();
       y = getY();
       cout << "X:" << x << "Y:" << y;
       // do some methods here after getting the x and y cords;
    }
```

Point.h

```
 #ifndef Point_Point_h
 #define Point_Point_h

class Point {
  private:
         int x,y;
  public : 

       Point() {
       x = 0;
       y = 0;
       }//default consrructor

      Point(int x,int y);
      int getX();
      int getY();
      void setX(int x);
      void setY(int y);
      void someMethods();
 };    

#endif
```

Comment: Replace `Point Point(x,y);` with `point.setX(x);` and `point.setY(y);` (you're never actually modifying `point` in your current example).

Comment: thanks for help. manage to understand it and get it already from the help of you guys

Answer (score 3):

In the main function, you have the statement

```
Point Point(x,y);
```

When I think you meant

```
Point point(x,y);
```

As it is, the `point.someMethods()` call below is using the global `point` object declared just before the main function, which I think is the problem.

Comment: thanks for help. manage to understand it and get it already from the help of you guys

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the someMethods() on the point object which is global which was created using the default constructor which initializes the x and y values to 0.

Use the below code.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{     
    int x,y;
    cout << "Please Enter x-Cordinate"<< endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please Enter y-Cordinate" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    Point point(x,y);

    //just putting here in main to show that X and Y value isn't passed
    point.someMethods(); // This should print the proper X and Y values
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. manage to understand it and get it already from the help of you guys

Answer (score 2):

You need to notice that you do `point.someMethods()`, while never actually changing `point` to be using x and y.

```
int x,y;
int main()
{     
    cout << "Please Enter x-Cordinate"<< endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please Enter y-Cordinate" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    Point point(x,y);

    //just putting here in main to show that X and Y value isn't passed
    point.someMethods(); <-- the output will always be X:0 Y:0 no matter what value the user input
}
```

Will work because now the point is created with x and y (notice I've deleted the point declaration from before the main function. You could alternatively declare it there and use its set functions).

Comment: thanks for help. manage to understand it and get it already from the help of you guys

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you have 2 "Point" objects in your program. One is instantiated here: "Point point;" and the other is instantiated here: "Point Point(x,y);".

In the end you're calling "point.someMethods();" using the first object, which was constructed using the default constructor, thus having x and y set as 0.

I believe in this case you should remove "Point point;" instantiation from the global namespace, and change the name of your "Point Point(x,y);" to "Point point(x,y);". Then it'll work as expected:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;
int x,y;

int main()
{     
    cout << "Please Enter x-Cordinate"<< endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please Enter y-Cordinate" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    Point point(x,y);

    //just putting here in main to show that X and Y value isn't passed
    point.someMethods(); <-- the output will always be X:0 Y:0 no matter what value the user input
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. manage to understand it and get it already from the help of you guys

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

You are not modifying your zero-initialized variable

```
Point point; // <---- only this variable is zero-initialized
int main()
{     
    // ...

    //just putting here in main to show that X and Y value isn't passed
    point.someMethods(); //<-- the output will always be X:0 Y:0 no matter what value the user input
//  ^^^^^ <--- again, still zero
}
```

### Solution

Instead do something like:

```
int main()
{     
    Point point(1,2); // <-- or read from std::cin

    //just putting here in main to show that X and Y value isn't passed
    point.someMethods(); //<-- value the user input
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/244ae2d60c128b06)

### Note

Just because you have the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) here, the canonical way to write your constructors would be

```
class Point
{
private:
   int x = 0; // any constructor which does explicitly set x or y
   int y = 0; // will take these in-class initializer values

public:
   // default constructor uses in-class initializer
   Point() = default; // sets to (0,0)

   // other constructor does NOT use setters but initialization list
   Point(int a, int b): x{a}, y{b} {} // sets to (a,b)
};
```

Comment: thanks for help. manage to understand it and get it already from the help of you guys

Comment: @jeremykeh note that you have written your constructors in a very non-idiomatic way, see the Note in my answer for how to do this in C++11

Answer (score 2):

You need to change Point Point(x,y); to Point point(x,y) and delete Point point;

Comment: thanks for help. manage to understand it and get it already from the help of you guys